# My New Game JButton is not working?

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am currently working on an assignment which I have 98% finished. I have made gui program where it has a jtextfield set to 0 but as you play the game it changes.

Now I have created a j button called "NEW GAME" and "QUIT". My Quit button works fine when clicked. but my new game button is my problem.

I want it so that when I click the button it sets the score to 0

```
 public ShinyButtonsGUIProgramToShare(String tit, int x, int y) {
        //The button GUI
        ShinyButtonsGUIToShare sbg = new ShinyButtonsGUIToShare("NYI", 552, 552, new ShinyButtons());
        sbg.setLocation(10, 10);
        getContentPane().add(sbg);
        //The score text and text box
        JLabel jlb = new JLabel("Score: ");
        jlb.setLocation(12, (y - 75));
        jlb.setSize(45, 40);
        getContentPane().add(jlb);

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("0");
        jtf.setLocation(60, (y - 70));
        jtf.setSize(150, 30);
        jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        getContentPane().add(jtf);


        JButton NewGame, Quit;
        NewGame = new JButton("New Game");
        Quit = new JButton("Quit");

        Quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            System.exit(0); 
          }});

        NewGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
          JTextField jtf.setText("0");
          }});


        NewGame.setLocation((x - 220), (y - 70));
        NewGame.setSize(100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(NewGame);

        Quit.setLocation((x - 110), (y - 70));
        Quit.setSize(100, 30);
        getContentPane().add(Quit);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // allow window to close 
        setSize(x, y);
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShinyButtonsGUIProgramToShare sbgp = new ShinyButtonsGUIProgramToShare("Shiny   Buttons", 578, 634);
        sbgp.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code, `JTextField jtf.setText("0");`, even compile? If it doesn't compile, then you're not 98% done.

Comment: And we're seeing a lot of these shiny button app type questions over the last two days. What is going on with this?

Comment: I see `setSize` and `setLocation` and little part of me dies...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: and whenever a coder writes `setLayout(null)`, a puppy dies somewhere.

Comment: ShinyButtonsGUIToShare sbg = new ShinyButtonsGUIToShare("NYI", 552, 552, new ShinyButtons()); . Why exactly are you passing in four parameters when ShinyButtonsGUIToShare's constructor only takes three parameters? Does your code even compile?

Comment: i know its an assignment for first year students and its way out of league to do. but really thats me only question.

Comment: @Solace I'd be more worried about this creating a recursive loop and crashing the program with stack overflow error, but what do I know :P

Comment: yes it compiles when i take the NewGame.addAction etc and erase it

Comment: it compiles and everything works except the new  game button

Comment: Oh nevermind. They're not the same thing.

Comment: Why is everyone with this shiny button question using null layouts and setting size/location? Use a Layout Manager like `GridLayout`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22138743/2587435)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a context issue...

The instance of `jtf` can not be referenced from within the context of the `NewGame`'s `ActionListener`

You need to make `jtf` and instance variable so it can be accessed from anywhere within an instance of `ShinyButtonsGUIProgramToShare` object.

Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: thanks i didn't use the action listner properly. i notced that was my mistake thanks.