# GridLayout Center Overflow Components

Tags: java, components, center

I have a set of buttons. My JPanel has a layout of GridLayout. I would like any components to go outside the square to get centered. Here is an image: http://screencast.com/t/z86ldR9vh

I would like the Options button to be centered under the group.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: setLayout(null) = complete freedom :-)

Comment: Just kidding. Have you considered using borderlayout or boxlayout? Gridbaglayout allows elements to span more than one cell.

Comment: `GridBagLayout` = complete freedom

Comment: @Solace To [quote @HovercraftFullOfEels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160760/my-new-game-jbutton-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment33631630_22160760), how many puppies do you intend to kill?

Comment: Most of my GUIs are made without layout managers...because elite programmers don't need them

Comment: I tried using BoxLayout but that just puts them all in a line, not in a grid like fashion. I want two rows of buttons. But with the last one centered so the button is not favoring one side or the other.

Comment: I would also like the GUI to resize by it's self, not me having to calculate the positions by my self all the time.

Comment: You will probably have to use a combination of `GridBagLayout` and `BoxLayout`.

Comment: Use proper layouts and then `pack()`.  No need to calculate anything.

Comment: Pack is only avalible on a frame, I am using a JPanel in another GridBagLayout for something that looks like the Minecraft main menu:http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/UDJeo5AYp6U/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Oh, I understand now with the GridBagLayout stuff... Ok Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another JPanel for the "Options" button and set it to flow layout.
For example, say the top panel is called "panel1" and the bottom is "panel2":

```
// create top panel with first four buttons
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
panel1.add(new JButton("Play"));
panel1.add(new JButton("New Game"));
panel1.add(new JButton("Save Game"));
panel1.add(new JButton("Load Game"));

// create bottom panel with "Options" button
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
panel2.add(new JButton("Options"));
```

Or, if you would like the complete code for the class (with all the imports):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class Buttons {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buttons gui = new Buttons();
    }

    public Buttons() {
        // create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // create top panel with first four buttons
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        panel1.add(new JButton("Play"));
        panel1.add(new JButton("New Game"));
        panel1.add(new JButton("Save Game"));
        panel1.add(new JButton("Load Game"));

        // create bottom panel with "Options" button
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.add(new JButton("Options"));

        // add panels to frame
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);
    }   
}
```