# Java GUI - Getting random value from array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, random

So I have this 2d array of buttons and I have an array of images. I want to get the images on the buttons but I want the images to be on random buttons every time the program starts. Like this:[What I want it to look like](http://gyazo.com/63ba7e3b233587549f18a5a0632dd57b). Right now I can only get one color to be on all of the buttons by changing the value of icons when I make the new JButton. What I think I need to do is have `Math.Random()` set to a variable and to get a random value from the array of images and then put the variable in `icons[]` when i declare the new `JButton` but I don't know if this is right and don't know how to do it. I did some searching and tried using this:

```
var randomValue = icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length)];
```

but I get an error saying

```
possible loss of precision, required int, found double.
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. If you want me to post the entire code let me know.

```
// 2D Array of buttons
buttons = new JButton[8][8];
    for(int row=0; row<8; row++) 
    {
        for (int col=0; col<8; col++) 
        {
            buttons[row][col] = new JButton(icons[0]);
            buttons[row][col].setLocation(6+col*70, 6+row*70);
            buttons[row][col].setSize(69,69);

            getContentPane().add(buttons[row][col]);
        }
    }

// Array of images
public static ImageIcon[] icons = {new ImageIcon("RedButton.png"),
                                   new ImageIcon("OrangeButton.png"),
                                   new ImageIcon("YellowButton.png"),
                                   new ImageIcon("GreenButton.png"),
                                   new ImageIcon("BlueButton.png"),
                                   new ImageIcon("LightGrayButton.png"),
                                   new ImageIcon("DarkGrayButton.png")};
```

Comment: try `randomValue = icons[(int)(Math.floor(Math.random() * icons.length))];`

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify this greatly by putting all my ImageIcons in an ArrayList, calling `java.util.Collections.shuffle(...)` on the ArrayList, and then passing out the ImageIcons from the shuffled ArrayList in order. Or if your buttons allow for repeated icons, then use a java.util.Random variable, say called `random` and simply call `random.nextInt(icons.length)` to get a random index for my array.

As an aside, please for your own sake, don't use null layout and absolute positioning. Your grid of JButtons is begging to be held in a GridLayout-using JPanel. Begging.

---

As an aside, why are you posting questions on the same project but using different names? You've similar posts  but different user names in both of your other posts here:

- [JButtons won't update on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138164/jbuttons-wont-update-on-button-click)
- [My New Game JButton is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160760/my-new-game-jbutton-is-not-working)

Comment: The reason im not using an arraylist is because this program is part of an assignment and it requires us to do it this way. Also, we were told to use null layout. Those actually aren't my posts btw, I guess someone else is having trouble on the assignment too. This is actually my first time using this site and I just made my account today. Thanks for the tips though!

Answer (score 0):

Before you set the icons on the JButton use this shuffle function...

```
public ImageIcon[] shuffle(ImageIcon[] icons)
{
    int index = 0;
    ImageIcon temp = 0;

    for(int i = icons.length -1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp = icons[index];
        icons[index] = icons[i];
        icons[i] = temp;
    }
    return icons;
}
```