# an ActionListener that resets a game when a JButton is pressed

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

Hi I am trying to reset my game with this ActionListener and method:

```
          newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          reset();
      }
    });
  }

  private void reset() {
      for(byte row=0; row<8; row++)
    {
      for(byte col=0; col<8; col++)
      {
        ImageIcon randomValue = icons[(byte)(Math.random() * icons.length)];
        shinyButtons[row][col] = new JButton(randomValue);
        shinyButtons[row][col].setLocation(10+col*69, 10+row*69);
        shinyButtons[row][col].setSize(69,69);
        getContentPane().add(shinyButtons[row][col]);
      }
    }
  }
```

But everytime I press the button, nothing happens, any help on how I can actually get it to reset it would be great!

heres my full code if needed:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ShinyButtonsApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  private static byte ROWS =8;
  ShinyButtons shiny = new ShinyButtons();


  public ImageIcon[] icons =
  {
    new ImageIcon("RedButton.png"),
    new ImageIcon("OrangeButton.png"),
    new ImageIcon("YellowButton.png"),
    new ImageIcon("GreenButton.png"),
    new ImageIcon("BlueButton.png"),
    new ImageIcon("LightGrayButton.png"),
    new ImageIcon("DarkGrayButton.png"),
  };  
  JButton[][] shinyButtons;

  public ShinyButtonsApp(String title)
  {
    super(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(578,634);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    shinyButtons = new JButton[8][8];


    for(byte row=0; row<8; row++)
    {
      for(byte col=0; col<8; col++)
      {
        ImageIcon randomValue = icons[(byte)(Math.random() * icons.length)];
        shinyButtons[row][col] = new JButton(randomValue);
        shinyButtons[row][col].setLocation(10+col*69, 10+row*69);
        shinyButtons[row][col].setSize(69,69);
        getContentPane().add(shinyButtons[row][col]);
      }
    }


    JButton red = new JButton(icons[0]);
    red.setLocation(200,200);
    red.setSize(69,69);
    getContentPane().add(red);

    //add the NEW GAME button
    JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    newGame.setLocation(350,570);
    newGame.setSize(100, 25);
    getContentPane().add(newGame);

    //add the QUIT button
    JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
    quit.setLocation(460, 570);
    quit.setSize(100,25);
    getContentPane().add(quit);

    //add the SCORE text field
    JTextField score = new JTextField();
    score.setText(Integer.toString(shiny.score));
    score.setEditable(false);
    score.setLocation(70, 577);
    score.setSize(100,20);
    getContentPane().add(score);

    //add the SCORE label
    JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score:");
    scoreLabel.setLocation(18,537);
    scoreLabel.setSize(100,100);
    getContentPane().add(scoreLabel);

     quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        System.exit(0);      
      }
    });  


          newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          reset();
      }
    });
  }

  private void reset() {
      for(byte row=0; row<8; row++)
    {
      for(byte col=0; col<8; col++)
      {
        ImageIcon randomValue = icons[(byte)(Math.random() * icons.length)];
        shinyButtons[row][col] = new JButton(randomValue);
        shinyButtons[row][col].setLocation(10+col*69, 10+row*69);
        shinyButtons[row][col].setSize(69,69);
        getContentPane().add(shinyButtons[row][col]);
      }
    }
  }


  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    ShinyButtonsApp buttons;
    buttons = new ShinyButtonsApp("Shiny Buttons");
    buttons.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Comment: Array indices are ints, not bytes. Using bytes instead of ints makes your code more complex for nothing.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22138743/2587435) helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `System.out.println()` to your reset() method to see what's going on:

```
private void reset() {
    for (byte row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (byte col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            ImageIcon randomValue = icons[(byte) (Math.random() * icons.length)];
            shinyButtons[row][col] = new JButton(randomValue);
            shinyButtons[row][col].setLocation(10 + col * 69, 10 + row * 69);
            shinyButtons[row][col].setSize(69, 69);
            getContentPane().add(shinyButtons[row][col]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(getContentPane().getComponentCount());
}
```

You are not removing the old buttons that you previously added.  Consider using a proper LayoutManager, such as GridLayout.  I would also rethink your design: you shouldn't need to remove and then re-add the buttons.  Store the state of your data separate from your UI.

Try this... Create a variable to store the game state:

```
private final ImageIcon[][] data = new ImageIcon[8][8];
```

Set up the game state in your reset() method:

```
private void reset() {  // no need to add the buttons again
    for (byte row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (byte col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            data[row][col] = icons[(byte) (Math.random() * icons.length)];
            shinyButtons[row][col].setIcon(data[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to initialize the game state when you first create the buttons:

```
    for (byte row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (byte col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            shinyButtons[row][col] = new JButton();
            shinyButtons[row][col].setLocation(10 + col * 69, 10 + row * 69);
            shinyButtons[row][col].setSize(69, 69);
            getContentPane().add(shinyButtons[row][col]);
        }
    }

    reset();
```

Comment: I just added the System.out.println(getContentPane().getComponentCount()); to my code and it just printed number value: 133
197
261
325
389
453
517
581
I am not really sure what that means

Comment: @user3330114 Take it to mean the number of buttons you've added to the getContentPane() JPanel.  You just keep adding more buttons, never removing them, just piling a new layer on top of each time.

Comment: do you have any suggestions as to how I could do that? removing stuff from an array doesn't seem like it would be easy