# Adjust size of JButtons and window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

The window must contain a `JPanel` that contains an 8 x 8 array of `JButtons`, each with a size of 69 x 69 pixels and displaying an `ImageIcon` instead of text. At the bottom of the window is a JLabel, a right­aligned JTextField and two more JButtons as shown. The window must be non­resizable with a size of 578 x 634 pixels. Upon startup, the window should show a random arrangement of colored buttons as shown.

This is what I have so far, any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShinyButtons extends JFrame 
{
    public static byte RED = 0;
    public static byte ORANGE = 1;
    public static byte YELLOW = 2;
    public static byte GREEN = 3;
    public static byte BLUE = 4;
    public static byte LIGHT_GRAY = 5;
    public static byte DARK_GRAY = 6;

    public static byte ROWS = 8;

    private byte[][] buttonTable;

    public ShinyButtons() 
    {
        buttonTable = new byte[ROWS][ROWS];
        resetButtons();
    }

    private void resetButtons() 
    {
        for (int r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
            for (int c=0; c<ROWS; c++)
                buttonTable[r][c] = (byte)(Math.random()*7);
    }

    public byte getButton(int r, int c) {
        return buttonTable[r][c];
    }

    public ShinyButtons (String title) { 
        super(title); // Set title of window 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // allow window to close 
        setSize(900, 300); // Set size of window      
    }

    public static ImageIcon[] icons = { 
            new ImageIcon("RedButton.png"), 
            new ImageIcon("OrangeButton.png"), 
            new ImageIcon("YellowButton.png"), 
            new ImageIcon("GreenButton.png"), 
            new ImageIcon("BlueButton.png"), 
            new ImageIcon("LightGrayButton.png"), 
            new ImageIcon("DarkGrayButton.png") 
        };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ShinyButtons frame; 
        frame = new ShinyButtons("Shiny Buttons");  // Create window     
        frame.setVisible(true); // Show window

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        ImageIcon r= new ImageIcon("RedButton.png");
        ImageIcon o= new ImageIcon("OrangeButton.png");
        ImageIcon y= new ImageIcon("YellowButton.png");
        ImageIcon g= new ImageIcon("GreenButton.png");
        ImageIcon b= new ImageIcon("BlueButton.png");
        ImageIcon l= new ImageIcon("LightGrayButton.png");
        ImageIcon d= new ImageIcon("DarkGrayButton.png");

        JButton btn;

        btn = new JButton(o);
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        panel.add(btn);

        panel.add(new JButton(r));
        panel.add(new JButton(o));
        panel.add(new JButton(y));
        panel.add(new JButton(g));
        panel.add(new JButton(b));
        panel.add(new JButton(l));
        panel.add(new JButton(d));

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Please ask an answerable question. Any question.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22138743/2587435)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pack` which allows the frame to use your contents preferred sizes to determine the size of the frame.

This is important, as this method takes into account the windows border decorations, which `setSize` doesn't

You should never makes assumptions about pixel sizes, especially when you're dealing with fonts, as these may be rendered at different sizes on different systems

Pixel perfect precision is an illusion, you should focus more on usability and flow and let the layout managers do their jobs...

Also note, its important to make the frame unresizable BEFORE you pack it

Comment: Thanks for your help. However now I am trying to make the buttons do something when I click them. I thought I would just have to implement ActionListener but that doesn't work. I get this error.     Error: ShinyButtons is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

Comment: So, implement the requirements of the [ActionListener interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score -1):

In the case you have fixed size button, jpanel and frame, you should use set the same value for both maximum and minimum for button, in this case is 69x69 , and set property resizable to false for panel and frame.